# Dynamic Form with Dynamic Select Box - Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, dynamic-forms

I was able to create a Dynamic form with a select box(When you select the AddItem button on the form a row will be added along with some fields and a dropbox will also be among those). Options of the dropbox is hard coded. What i am trying is to get the options from the database. How can i achieve this?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

var i = 0;
      $('#add_jobitem').click(function(){
        i++;
        $('#jobitem tr:last').after('<tr>'+
          '<td>'+
              '<select name="jobitem_name[] id=jobitem_name['+i+']">'+
                '<option value="Item1">Item1</option>'+
                '<option value="Item2">Item2</option>'+
                '<option value="Other">Other</option>'+
              '</select>'+
          '</td>'+
          '<td><input name="jobitem_description[]" id="jobitem_description['+i+']" class="jobitem_description" placeholder="Description"></td>'+
          '<td><input name="jobitem_qty[]" id="jobitem_qty['+i+']" class="jobitem_qty" placeholder="Qty" oninput="calculate_jobitem_total()" onchange="calculate_jobitem_total()"></td>'+
          '<td><input name="jobitem_each_price[]" id="jobitem_each_price['+i+']" class="jobitem_each_price" placeholder="Each Price" oninput="calculate_jobitem_total()" onchange="calculate_jobitem_total()"></td>'+
          '<td><input name="jobitem_total[]" id="jobitem_total['+i+']" class="jobitem_total" placeholder="Total"></td>'+
          '<td>'+
          '<select name="jobitem_vendor[] id=jobitem_vendor['+i+']">'+
            '<option value="Vendo1">Vendor1</option>'+
            '<option value="Vendo2">Vendor2</option>'+
          '</select>'+
          '</td>'+
          '<td><input name="jobitem_po_number[]" id="jobitem_po_number['+i+']" class="jobitem_po_number" placeholder="PO Number"></td>'+
        '</tr>');
       });
  });
</script>
```

What i need is to fill the jobitem_vendor[] through the database

Comment: It would help if you posted the code relevant to this issue so we can offer a solution tailored around your existing code. At this point the question is a little to broad.

Comment: @Bogdan i have added some code

Answer (score 0):

To get the options from the database, pass them from your controller to the view:

```
$options = Item::all()->sortby('name', SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE)->pluck('name', 'id');
```

Pass this variable to your view:

```
return view('jobs.index', ['options' => $options]);
```

In your javascript:

```
var options = {!! json_encode($options) !!};
```

You can then use the options from the database when building up your select field.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using laravelcollective/html, you can put this directly to your  JS script

```
{!! Form::select('jobitem_name[]', App\JobItem::pluck('name', 'id') ) !!}
```

In your javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

var i = 0;
      $('#add_jobitem').click(function(){
        i++;
        $('#jobitem tr:last').after('<tr>'+
          '<td>'+
              '{!! Form::select('jobitem_name[]', App\JobItem::pluck('name', 'id') ) !!}'+
          '</td>'+
          '<td><input name="jobitem_description[]" id="jobitem_description['+i+']" class="jobitem_description" placeholder="Description"></td>'+
          '<td><input name="jobitem_qty[]" id="jobitem_qty['+i+']" class="jobitem_qty" placeholder="Qty" oninput="calculate_jobitem_total()" onchange="calculate_jobitem_total()"></td>'+
          '<td><input name="jobitem_each_price[]" id="jobitem_each_price['+i+']" class="jobitem_each_price" placeholder="Each Price" oninput="calculate_jobitem_total()" onchange="calculate_jobitem_total()"></td>'+
          '<td><input name="jobitem_total[]" id="jobitem_total['+i+']" class="jobitem_total" placeholder="Total"></td>'+
          '<td>'+
          '<select name="jobitem_vendor[] id=jobitem_vendor['+i+']">'+
            '<option value="Vendo1">Vendor1</option>'+
            '<option value="Vendo2">Vendor2</option>'+
          '</select>'+
          '</td>'+
          '<td><input name="jobitem_po_number[]" id="jobitem_po_number['+i+']" class="jobitem_po_number" placeholder="PO Number"></td>'+
        '</tr>');
       });
  });
</script>
```